# Browser Extension vs Sys Tray Apps

Tags: c++, plugins, cross-browser, google-chrome-extension

I have a request to write an end user app that needs to be cross-browser, platform-agnostic - HTTP/HTTPS sniffer (I know this part can be accomplished) for data gathering, analysis and HTTP posting the data to a server. Can anyone throw some light on the pros cons of going sys tray app vs browser extension. More so about the limitations of the browser extensions 
- What I can and I can't do. 
- Can I persist (db4o,SQLlite) the traffic data and do CRUD operations on it?
- Can browser extensions be asynchronous? without affecting user performance?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a HTTP sniffer extension in Chrome using their APIs, you have to go through the C++ route and create a cross platform NPAPI plugin that your extension can access:

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/npapi.html

Answers to your questions:

- Rapid install, they just click on "Install" within the browser, and the extension is automatically installed.
- Cross platform, you can create a single extension that will work on all platforms (embed platform specific plugins).
- Easy development, your development will all be in JavaScript that communicates to your plugin through JavaScript. In the plugin, you only deal with the inputs and the outputs. Everything is like a black box. You can use [firebreath](http://code.google.com/p/firebreath/).
- HTML5 [Web SQL Storage](http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/webdatabase/todo/) or keyvalue [LocalStorage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/) and [IndexDB](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/IndexedDB/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#introduction)
- Use HTML5 [WebWorkers](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-workers/current-work/) for asynchronous operations.
- Plugins can do asynchronous callbacks too!

Since your using NPAPI, there is no limit. Your NPAPI can create a SysTray icon if you want to as well. The cons of using NPAPI is that, your extension becomes dangerous to the end-user, since you are technically executing native code.

Comment: Can't I use XPCOM as in the example https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_School/Intercepting_Page_Loads#HTTP_Observers